# Return a data frame using replicate command

Tags: r, r-mosaic

The "do" command from the mosaic package nicely returns a data frame by default.

```
require(mosaic)
require(Sleuth3)


nulldist1 <- do(10)*t.test(Incidents~shuffle(Launch),
                           data=case0401,var.equal=TRUE)$statistic
class(nulldist1)
```

Now, I'd like to use the replicate command to do the same thing. Is there an argument that one can set in the replicate command that will force it to return a data frame? I tried simplify="data.frame" but that didn't work.

```
nulldist2 <- replicate(10,{
  t.test(Incidents~shuffle(Launch),
         data=case0401,var.equal=TRUE)$statistic
})
class(nulldist2)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.frame(result = replicate(10,t.test(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))$statistic))
```

Comment: I'll rephrase; this is redundant to assign to `result` in a data frame call. Even though it works, `as.data.frame()` or even `data.frame()` without assigning to `result` is clearer and more direct (with the latter calling `as.data.frame` as described in `?data.frame` - hence cut out the middle man and call it directly!)

Comment: The command nulldist2 <- data.frame(t=replicate(10,{
  t.test(Incidents~shuffle(Launch),
         data=case0401,var.equal=TRUE)$statistic
})) is like the command df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3)), it doesn't create a variable t, it makes the name of the first column t, which is what I wanted so that the replicate command gives exactly the same result as the do command.

Comment: The whole point of the "result = " is to rename the column. Without it the column will have a long unwieldy name. Its completely optional, I just like it cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you read `?replicate` you'll notice that there is no `simplify = "data.frame"` option and hence it is no surprise that that didn't work.

As `replicate()` returns an array, and assuming the result is a 2-d array, just use `as.data.frame()` on the object `nulldist2`

```
nulldist2 <- as.data.frame(nulldist2)
```

Here's an example:

```
> arr <- replicate(10, quantile(rnorm(1000)))
> arr
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]         [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
0%   -3.3574313 -3.09705035 -2.85009578 -3.140181733 -2.94235439 -3.24334919
25%  -0.6610031 -0.68506227 -0.66891111 -0.681785814 -0.66985211 -0.60439317
50%   0.0576617  0.05899849 -0.01235571  0.007168725  0.07139977  0.07511633
75%   0.7584004  0.67879534  0.69335820  0.659121437  0.72854080  0.76506110
100%  3.0837762  2.89445426  3.23701556  3.084539130  3.06543839  3.07470137
            [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       [,10]
0%   -2.78486552 -3.44680297 -3.27408224 -2.87007187
25%  -0.69813726 -0.62989631 -0.68281294 -0.61806994
50%  -0.02589364  0.03913355 -0.04370316  0.05563488
75%   0.66519651  0.74677634  0.64744094  0.74664823
100%  3.13266873  4.64939039  2.68895458  3.16797447
> df <- as.data.frame(t(arr))
> df
          0%        25%          50%       75%     100%
1  -3.357431 -0.6610031  0.057661700 0.7584004 3.083776
2  -3.097050 -0.6850623  0.058998490 0.6787953 2.894454
3  -2.850096 -0.6689111 -0.012355714 0.6933582 3.237016
4  -3.140182 -0.6817858  0.007168725 0.6591214 3.084539
5  -2.942354 -0.6698521  0.071399769 0.7285408 3.065438
6  -3.243349 -0.6043932  0.075116334 0.7650611 3.074701
7  -2.784866 -0.6981373 -0.025893640 0.6651965 3.132669
8  -3.446803 -0.6298963  0.039133547 0.7467763 4.649390
9  -3.274082 -0.6828129 -0.043703156 0.6474409 2.688955
10 -2.870072 -0.6180699  0.055634885 0.7466482 3.167974
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```